# Mongoose return value from withTransaction callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

I want to utilize mongoose's `withTransaction` helper particularly for its ability to automatically retry transient transaction errors. However, it seems that the `withTransaction` helper is incapable of returning data, which is a problem for me.

I have code that looks like:

```
import { startSession } from 'mongoose';

async addItem(itemData) {
    const session = await startSession();
 
    session.startTransaction();
    try {
        const item = await new Item({ itemData }).save({ session });
        
        // a bunch of other async operations...

       await session.commitTransaction();
       session.endSession();

       return item;
    } catch (error) {
        await session.abortTransaction();
        session.endSession();
        throw error;
    }
}
```

How can I either (1) use the `withTransaction` helper but still have this function returning the `item` as it currently does, or (2) make this function automatically retry on transient transaction errors through some way other than using `withTransaction`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be a [known issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-2014) in the node driver. Some workarounds are provided in that ticket.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple helper that internally uses `withTransaction` to solve the problem and make transactions less verbose with mongoose.

After installing [mongoose-trx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-trx) you can simply do:

```js
const transaction = require('mongoose-trx');

const [customer] = await transaction(session => Customer.create([{ name: 'Test' }], { session }));

// do whatever you need to do with the customer then return it
```

It supports transaction options as well, see the documentation on how to do it.